# Replace single quotes in objective c

Tags: objective-c

For replacing of the single quote (') i was using:

```
 NSString *value = @"S't";
 value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"withString:@"\'"];
```

Expected result:

```
value = @"S\'t"
```

Real result:

```
value = @"S't"
```

Unfortunality this method is not working as i expected.
As i understand it is problem with detection of the ' if it is surround by letters. Could you share you're experience how it is possible to handle this.

Comment: `... withString:@"\\'"` ?

Comment: Simply add `@"\\'"` instead of `@"\'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` character, as it is the special "escape" character itself.

```
value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'"withString:@"\\'"];
```

Comment: Actual result is @"B\\'t" is it right if i need simple @"B\'t"